# How do I access flashmessenger in my layout file, in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to display my flash messages in my application's layout file - not sure how to access it though.  I set the value in my action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my view helper - https://github.com/philBrown/Tolerable/blob/master/library/Tolerable/View/Helper/FlashMessenger.php

This even includes translations if you have them configured.

To display messages from the default namespace, simply use

```
<?php echo $this->flashMessenger() ?>
```

To set a namespace, provide it as the first argument

```
<?php echo $this->flashMessenger('errors') ?>
```

The default is to render each message in an unordered list however you can change that by providing a view partial

```
<?php echo $this->flashMessenger(null, 'flash-messages-partial.phtml') ?>
```