# FlashMessenger in Zend 2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am doing zend 2 Study. Now I checkout flashMessenger helper. It seems there are no documented way to call flashMessenger at layout.php. because I want to show all messages (error or success) at div located at layout, I need to call flashMessenger there. I do not want to send messages everytime via controller's actions and just want action only add message and layout show them.

While I am open to custom helper/libs But builtin solution is the best.
( I do not much work on zend 1 also, So I did not know if it is easily possible with even zend 1. )

I checkout one post [How do I access flashmessenger in my layout file, in zend framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285131/how-do-i-access-flashmessenger-in-my-layout-file-in-zend-framework?rq=1) But it have custom solution for zend 1. So I am thinking if zend have no built in solution at all in both 1 & 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just wrote my own simple viewhelper:

```
<?php

namespace My\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class FlashMessenger extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected static $_flashMessenger;

    public function __invoke($namespace = 'default') {

        if (!self::$_flashMessenger) {

            self::$_flashMessenger = new \Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger;
        }

        return self::$_flashMessenger->setNamespace($namespace);
    }
}
```

use it like:

```
<? if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()): ?>
    <ul>
    <? foreach ($this->flashMessenger()->getMessages() as $message): ?>
        <li><?= $message></li>
    <? endforeach ?>
    </ul>
<? endif ?>
```

Comment: Late to check (I am newbie on ZF2 that time :) ). But yes it works as View helper.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller method  add this

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Your Flash message');
```

In module/Application/view/layout/{your-layout.phtml} add this:

```
<div>
 <?php if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <?php foreach ($this->flashMessenger()->getMessages() as $message): ?>
            <?php echo $message; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think this will help solve your problem.