# PHP message on the same page

Tags: php

Hi I have something similar in my code;

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="processMaster.php">
<input type="submit" id="testOne" name="testOne" value="Process me">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the processMaster.php reads as follows;

```
<?php
echo "Boom!";
?>
```

Now that this works fine.

But my issue is once the "Boom!" appears, it appear in a separate page(or in a page where all the other elements of the page is not displayed.)

Is there a possibility/workaround that I can print the message on the same page where I can also see the Process me button too visible?

Comment: You will need AJAX for that OR Say this file is saved as INDEX.PHP So, after the Echo put a include("INDEX.PHP") to pull both pages... Alternatively opening using echo file_get_contents("INDEX.PHP") may also solve it temporarily. But AJAX helpes a lot it solving these problems

Comment: Set the message in session (to an array) and remove it after it has been displayed. On this way there are realised all FlashMessengers in frameworks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136855/flashmessenger-in-zend-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

processMaster.php should contain the following:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="processMaster.php">
<input type="submit" id="testOne" name="testOne" value="Process me">
</form>
<?php 
if($_POST['testOne'] != NULL){
  echo "Boom!"'
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @alfasin! however i figure out  if(isset($_POST['testOne'])) {
  echo "BOOM!";
} is much more appropriate in my case. thanks again!

Comment: @DKarolis from the manual: `isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL` http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

and you're most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

To submit to the same page use

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

and check for the presence of $_POST variables to decide what to display